# Set private variable in construct not working

Tags: php, function, class, variables, static

Here is my working code:-

```
public static function getOperatingSys() {

    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    $osPlatform = "Unknown OS";

    $osArray = array(
        '/windows nt 10/i'     =>  'Windows 10',
        '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
        '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8'
        );

    foreach ($osArray as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $osPlatform = $value;
        }

    }   

    return $osPlatform;
}
```

---

As you can see `$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` is working.

However, how can I convert it to this?:

```
private $user_agent;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }

    public static function getOperatingSys() {

        $osPlatform = "Unknown OS";

        $osArray = array(
            '/windows nt 10/i'     =>  'Windows 10',
            '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
            '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8'
            );

        foreach ($osArray as $regex => $value) { 

            if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
                $osPlatform = $value;
            }

        }   

        return $osPlatform;
    }
```

I am putting `private $user_agent` but how can i make it so that it equals `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` and then how can i use it/call it in my function `getOperatingSys()`?

Comment: `if (preg_match($regex, $this->user_agent)) {`

Comment: @Anant I get this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that you need to change is to make getOperatingSys no longer a static function. The second thing would be to then use $this-> when referencing user_agent. Something like the below should work:

```
private $user_agent;

public function __construct() {
    $this->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}

public function getOperatingSys() {

    $osPlatform = "Unknown OS";

    $osArray = array(
        '/windows nt 10/i'     =>  'Windows 10',
        '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
        '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8'
        );

    foreach ($osArray as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $this->$user_agent)) {
            $osPlatform = $value;
        }

    }   

    return $osPlatform;
}
```

Comment: just a question: why would i remove static? i dont understand, thanx

Comment: As soon as you have switched to declaring something in a class you are now using object oriented programming. With object oriented programming you are defining a class, that has a state and operations you can perform on it to either manipulate the state, or perform operations. A function that is not static refers to a particular instance of your class that has the state that you can modify. A function that is static on the other hand doesn't refer to a particular instance so you can't access variables within any particular instance. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: ok thanks. now in my original working code (before I changed it to your code), which one is better? my original code or your new code?

Comment: It really depends on what you are using this for. With a user agent, since I am guessing you have a single instance of your class and not multiple, a class may be overkill, unless you are planning to add lots of other functionality to the class. That is where depending on your usage the answer I have or the answer @Anant provided have different positives and negatives that we could get into. But it really depends on the overall goal of what you're using this code for? Are you planning on adding other methods to it to get additional information? Is the rest of your application object oriented?